# OpenAdaptor vs Apache Camel

Tags: apache, routes, comparison, apache-camel

I want to select a Routing and Transformation tool. I found camel and OpenAdapter suitable for my setup.

Can someone tell me which one to use ? 
Any comparison(advantage and drawbacks) among both ?

Thanks,

Anuj

Answer (score 1):

This is also being discussed at the Apache Camel mailing list

- http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Apache-Camel-vs-Openadaptor-tp5750436.html

From this list you can see that OpenAdaptor is a dead project. Also Apache Camel has a very vibrant and big community. So you should go for Camel if you only have these 2 choices.

Mind that instead of OpenAdaptor there may be other Camel like alternatives you can explore. We have some links to those from this page:

- http://camel.apache.org/articles

.. in the comparison to Camel's competitors section.

Comment: Fully agree. The last version of OpenAdaptor is from 2011. You probably do not want to use a software with no updates.

Comment: It was helpful Claus. One more thing: What are the performance stats of camel. I didn't find any performance results ?

Comment: There is no official performance statistics. You should test it yourself - performance variates a lot depending on a lot of factors. Its not like a racecar which can go as fast as 250km/h, and that compare that against another racecar that goes 280km/h.

Comment: Thanks Claus for your response :)